# e.KeyCode and KeyEventArgs not working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a webcam program and I want to start my webcam by pressing the space bar, so I tried the following code:

```
private void mainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)

                webcam.Start(0);
        }
```

And using System.Windows.Input will show this error:

```
Error   2   'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebCam\Window1.xaml.cs    44  19  WebCam
```

and when I use System.Windows.Forms it shows:

```
Error   1   No overload for 'mainWindow_PreviewKeyDown' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler' C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebCam\Window1.xaml   4   47  WebCam
```

How do I get past this?
Also I'm using Visual Studios 2012 Express.

Comment: Is this a WPF Application?

Comment: Do it in the *actual* KeyDown event, not PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: if you debug 'e', is there an option for 'KeyCode' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `ProcessCmdKey` as below:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {

               if (keyData == Keys.Space)
               {
                webcam.Start(0);
                    return true;
                }

            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the OnPreviewKeyDown like so:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Space key down");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted it to be the space bar only, but this actually works alright, thanks!

Comment: Changed the code a bit. Will also work with only the spacebar

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is doable, the issue is that, although your method was written for the **PreviewKeyDownEventArgs** (which is being told to us by its name: *mainWindow_PreviewKeyDown*), it is in fact using **KeyPressEventArgs**. Probably that is the reason for your confusion.

Looking at **KeyPressEventArgs** we find that it doesn't have a **KeyCode** object. It does have however a KeyChar that we can use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#properties

By rewriting your conditional value, you can activate the webcam on the press of the desired button using your current event.

```
private void mainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Space)

            webcam.Start(0);
    }
```

I suggest that you rename your method to what it really is doing afterwards to avoid further misinterpretations.