# Check following C# code

Tags: c#, wpf

[Errors in My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoZq8.png)[image: My C# Code]

I am creating a wpf calculator app.In the picture working area is the name of my text block.I want to Add a keydown event on the textblock but the code is showing error.Please give me any solution if you have.

Code:

```
private void workingarea_previewkeydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1) 
    { 
        workingarea.Text == workingarea.Text + "1"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of taking a screenshot

Comment: private void workingarea_previewkeydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
            {
                workingarea.Text == workingarea.Text + "1";
            }
        }

Comment: It is an unholy mix of Winforms and WPF code.  It is unclear why the IntelliSense popup cannot help you discover e.Key.  Use `=` instead of `==` to assign the Text property.

Comment: Can i use key = to assign text property

Answer (score 1):

could you please move the mouse over the error to show us more information about your situation, you can click the bottom button at your left with the text "Error list".
Maybe the probleme is related to **System.Windows.Forms**

Edit:

You Missabled **PreviewKeyDownEventArgs** with **KeyEventArgs**

```
private void workingarea_previewkeydown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgse)
```

Control.PreviewKeyDown Event

```
private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Up:
            e.IsInputKey = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Control.KeyDown Event

```
void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Up:
            if (button1.ContextMenuStrip != null)
            {
                button1.ContextMenuStrip.Show(button1,
                    new Point(0, button1.Height), ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129727/e-keycode-and-keyeventargs-not-working#20129787.
this is not related to the probleme but instead of
workingarea.Text == workingarea.Text + "1"; 
i think you want to do this
workingarea.Text = workingarea.Text + "1"; 
a more good way to do it
workingarea.Text += "1";

Comment: this was also one error but one more error is shown in line 36 of my code.

Comment: the error is that you are using KeyEventArgs instead of PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.


void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) is for KeyDown event, private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) is for previewkeydown